# Ways to play music/sound on the background

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I want to play a small music on my website when users log in. But the prob is if I use HTML5 audio then it will slow down the speed and page load will take more time (I may lose visitors). Any ways to load music without slowing down page load? Music is not pause-able so I need the player to be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple:

```
<embed src="background_music.mp3" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="true">
```

As **JohnnyJS** said, it won't slow down your website, because it'll start only after all the elements and images are downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You really dont need using HTML5.

and that has nothing to do with page load, the function that calling the music will get called only after all elements loaded and images downloaded.

im sure that will help you:

[Next time just google it. :)](https://www.google.com/search?q=js%20music%20sound)